# How can I insert the content of arrays into a vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, callback, stdvector

I need to write some simple code with `std::vector`s and I am struggling a bit.

I have a `char[]` buffer that is filled with callback data from another program. I need to append this data to the end of a vector - the whole buffer.

```cpp
std::vector<char> vector; 

// data comes from another program
void callback(char buffer[], size_t size)
{
    // copy buffer to the end of vector here   
}
```

At the end the vector is supposed to contain continuous data from the buffer.

Is there an effective way to do this without inserting element by element with a loop?

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    vector.push_back(buffer[i]);
```

Comment: How do you know the size of the buffer ? Or if it's not completely filled, how many character there are ?

Comment: Search keywords: std::copy, std::back_inserter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you know the size, you can insert a range:

```
vector.insert(vector.end(), buffer, buffer + size);
```

There's also a more generic algorithm for this sort of thing:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(buffer, buffer + size, std::back_inserter(vector));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) (`#include <iterator>`) to get begin and end iterators of the array :

```
vector.insert(vector.begin(), std::begin(buffer), std::end(buffer))
```

Comment: `begin` and `end` only work if `buffer` is an array (not a pointer). It probably won't be here (although, without seeing the callback arguments, I can't be 100% sure).

Answer (score 1):

How about increasing the vector size by the required amount, and doing a memcpy?

Comment: That would probably be less efficient than `insert` or `std::copy`, since it would zero-initialise the new elements before copying over them. (It would also be more verbose, and less generic since `memcpy` only works for trivial types).

Comment: Agreed, using the standard library is better